# updating D3js graph with json data

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I am new to d3js by seeing examples i tried out something and finally built a graph in which i have used json data that comes from back bean and i acces it using a jsf component which is hidden and gets updated for 1 second. Now i want to update the SVG according to the data. 
`
        //

```
                                                $("#graphDiv").animate({
                                                    height : "toggle"
                                                }, 2000, function() {
                                                })

                                                $("#graphDiv").css({
                                                    "display" : "block"
                                                });
                                                InitChart();
                                            } else {

                                                $("#graphDiv").css({
                                                    "display" : "none"
                                                });

                                            }
                                        });

                        function InitChart() {
                            try {
                                var x=(${rawEventsMB.jsonString});
                                var data1=JSON.stringify(x);
                                var data = JSON.parse(data1); 
                                var parseDate = d3.time
                                        .format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse;
                                bisectDate = d3.bisector(function(d) {
                                    return d.time;
                                }).left;

                                data.forEach(function(d) {
                                    d.time = parseDate(d.time);
                                    d.count = +d.count;
                                });

                                var vis = d3.select("#visualisation"), WIDTH = 1000, HEIGHT = 300, MARGINS = {
                                    top : 20,
                                    right : 20,
                                    bottom : 20,
                                    left : 50
                                },

                                xScale = d3.time.scale().domain(
                                        [ d3.min(data, function(d) {
                                            return d.time;
                                        }), d3.max(data, function(d) {
                                            return d.time;
                                        }) ]).range(
                                        [ MARGINS.left,
                                                WIDTH - MARGINS.right ]),

                                yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                                        .range([ HEIGHT - MARGINS.top,MARGINS.bottom ])
                                        .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {return d.count;})),

                                xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale)
                                        .orient("bottom")
                                        .ticks(10)
                                        .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%d %b %X")),
                                yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale)
                                        .orient("left");

                                vis.append("svg:g")
                                        .attr("class", "x axis")
                                        .attr("transform","translate(0,"+ (HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom)+ ")")
                                        .call(xAxis)
                                        .selectAll("text").style("text-anchor","end")
                                        .attr("dx","-.6em")
                                        .attr("dy","-.55em")
                                        .attr("transform","rotate(-90)"),
                                vis.append("text")
                                        .attr("transform","translate("+ (WIDTH / 2)+ " ,"+ (HEIGHT + MARGINS.bottom*4)+ ")")
                                        .style("text-anchor","middle")
                                        .style("fill", "red")
                                        .style("font-weight", "bold")
                                        .text("Time");

                                vis.append("svg:g")
                                        .attr("class", "y axis")
                                        .attr("transform","translate("+ (MARGINS.left)+ ",0)")
                                        .call(yAxis), 
                                vis.append("text")
                                        .attr("transform","rotate(-90 "+ MARGINS.left* 1.4 + " "+ HEIGHT / 5 + ")")
                                        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                                        .style("fill", "red")
                                        .text("Number of events ")
                                        .style("font-weight", "bold");

                                var focus = vis.append("g").style(
                                        "display", "none");

                                focus.append("circle").attr("class", "y")
                                        .style("fill", "blue").style(
                                                "stroke", "blue").attr("r",
                                                4);

                                /* focus.append("text").attr("class","y").style("text-anchor","middle")
                                .style("fill", "red").style("font-weight", "bold"); */

                                focus.append("foreignObject")
                                .attr("width", 180)
                                .attr("height", 500).style("font", "bold 11px 'Helvetica Neue'").style("fill", "red").attr("class", "tooltip");

                                // append the rectangle to capture mouse              
                                vis.append("rect").attr("width", WIDTH)
                                        .attr("height", HEIGHT).style(
                                                "fill", "none").style(
                                                "pointer-events", "all")
                                        .on("mouseover", function() {
                                            focus.style("display", null);
                                        }).on("mouseout", function() {
                                            focus.style("display", "none");
                                        }).on("mousemove", mousemove);

                                var lineGen = d3.svg.line().x(function(d) {
                                    return xScale(d.time);
                                }).y(function(d) {
                                    return yScale(d.count);
                                }).interpolate("interpolation");

                                vis.append('svg:path').attr('d',
                                        lineGen(data)).attr('stroke',
                                        'green').attr('stroke-width', 2)
                                        .attr('fill', 'none');

                            } catch (ex) {
                                alert(ex);
                            }
                            function mousemove() {
                                var formatTime = d3.time.format("%e %b %X");
                                var x0 = xScale.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]), i = bisectDate(
                                        data, x0, 1), d0 = data[i - 1], d1 = data[i], d2 = x0
                                        - d0.time > d1.time - x0 ? d1 : d0;
                                focus.select("circle.y").attr(
                                        "transform",
                                        "translate(" + xScale(d2.time)
                                                + "," + yScale(d2.count)
                                                + ")"),
                                /* focus.select("text")
                                        .attr("transform","translate(" + xScale(d2.time)+ "," + yScale(d2.count)+ ")"); */
                                focus.select("foreignObject").attr("transform","translate(" + xScale(d2.time)+ "," + yScale(d2.count)+ ")")
                                .html("time:"+formatTime(d2.time)+", <br/> " + "count:"+d2.count);

                            }
                            var myVar=setTimeout(function() { InitChart(); }, 1000);
                        }
                    });
    //]]>
</script>`
```

After this how can i update the data if i do update the jsf component, i am ending up with graph that gets overlapped all the data, axis etc... can anyone please help me out.

I have another problem too  the browser console is showing  "ReferenceError:InitChart() is undefined" even when the function is called after using window.ready of jquery

Comment: cant i update the data periodically and call the InitChart function with the updated data as arguments??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into the d3 update pattern https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218

You need to separate your data binding code where you append paths with attribute `.data()` into a function which you can call whenever your data updates.

Also check out http://www.toptal.com/d3-js/towards-reusable-d3-js-charts it is a great way to structure your d3 charts

Comment: Tried doing this, but ended up with some other error.....  please help me out     http://stackoverflow.com/q/35405029/5388050